sympy.Piecewise with numpy array
I'd like to implement
sympy.Piecewise
on numpy arrays.
Consider:
import numpy as np
from sympy import Piecewise

x = np.array([0.1,1,2])
y = np.array([10,10,10])
Piecewise((x * y, x > 0.9),(0, True))

However, when I tried running it I got the following error:
TypeError: Argument must be a Basic object, not ndarray
Is there a way to get around this?
I've tried list comprehension. However, it gets more difficult when there are more variables involved.

In general numpy and sympy don't mix.  Bits and pieces may work, but it's better to use one or the other, not both.

The simpy.Piecewise is not directly compatible with numpy arrays. Use np.where to achieve similar functionality:
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0.1,1,2])
y = np.array([10,10,10])
result = np.where(x > 0.9, x * y, 0)

